# Is unidirectional strain data appropriate for 3D plasticity analysis?

Tags: material-science, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

It is usual practice to characterize material properties using uniaxial stress strain data. One can get plastic strain and true stress from the raw testing data. Many finite element analysis codes accept this uniaxial data for 3D plasticity analysis using von Mises plasticity. How can one use 1D data for 3D analysis? It would be very helpful if someone explains this.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you just have to choose at the outset that you're going to use the isotropic-hardening von Mises yield condition and a co-directional flow rule (normal Mises plasticity). At that point, you can calibrate the model parameters using uniaxial data. It is required that the user know that the chosen model is appropriate for the problem at hand.

If, for example, you're using a crystal plasticity model, you obviously have a lot more work to do to calibrate the model than with isotropic-hardening Mises plasticity. Such a model could not be calibrated with purely uniaxial data, so you would need to provide more.